# How to add whitespace for array of IBAN properly

Tags: javascript, regex, iban

I want to ask a question about regex.

I have an array of IBAN.

eg `["DE46700202700663820656", "DE07860700240455474700"]`

I want to add whitespace between each 4 characters.

eg `"DE46 7002 0270 0663 8206 56"`

Currently I use this regex.

`String(this.props.invoiceData.iban).replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ').split(',')`

It could add whitespace but regex does not restart for a second IBAN and second IBAN is destroyed.

eg `["DE46 7002 0270 0663 8206 56", "D E078 6070 0240 4554 7470 0"]`

What should I do to show two IBAN with proper whitespace as below?

eg `["DE46 7002 0270 0663 8206 56", "DE07 8607 0024 0455 4747 00"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It could add whitespace but regex does not restart for a second IBAN and second IBAN is destroyed.

That's because the regex is keeping state. Either:

1. Create it each time, or
2. Set `lastIndex` to 0 before using it

Here's #1:

```js
var ibans = ["DE46700202700663820656", "DE07860700240455474700"];
ibans = ibans.map(function(iban) {
  return iban.replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 ');
});
console.log(ibans);
```

Unless you're using an **ancient** JavaScript engine that has an issue with not recreating literal regular expressions each time (we're talking Firefox 3.0x or thereabouts), that should be fine.

Here's #2:

```js
var rex = /(.{4})/g;
var ibans = ["DE46700202700663820656", "DE07860700240455474700"];
ibans = ibans.map(function(iban) {
  rex.lastIndex = 0;
  return iban.replace(rex, '$1 ');
});
console.log(ibans);
```

Obviously, both can be shortened if you can use ES2015+ arrow functions and such...

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I didn't know about lastIndex.

Comment: @aaayumi: No worries. :-) As a side note, you don't need that capture group, you can use `$&` to refer to the match itself: `.replace(/.{4}/g, '$& ')`

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var a = ["DE46700202700663820656", "DE07860700240455474700"];
var b = a.map(i => i.replace(/(.{4})/g, '$1 '));
console.log(b)
```